# What's the point of the "From Review" link in LQ canned comments?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

When reviewers in the Low Quality Posts review queue recommend the deletion of a post, they have the option to leave a canned comment, and many reviewers do indeed leave such comments. The system adds a "From Review" link at the end which goes to the review item. Users without the edit privilege (2K on launched sites) are able to see the votes of each reviewer, while those with the privilege can cast their own vote if they have not already done so.

I am concerned that this automatic link may not be desirable behavior, especially for new users. Specifically:

1. Clicking the link shows their post under the heading **Low Quality Posts**. It's kind of like a "ha ha, computer thinks you did bad." This probably doesn't make users feel too good, especially if the post was fine and one reviewer made a mistake.
2. Looking at the list of specific users that recommended deletion feels like a "ho ho, look at all these people that think you did bad." Note that reviewers appear in this list even if they didn't leave the canned comment.
3. Users without the first review privilege (500 on launched sites) probably won't have seen the review interface before, and aren't expected to have read up on the review process or the LQP workflow.

In general, it just doesn't seem that the link needs to be publicly visible.

The only advantage that I can see of the link is that it lets community members with the edit privilege see that the post landed in LQP and that they might want to review it too. Maybe the link should be made a little indicator like the parenthesized number next to *close* or *edit*?

Does the "From Review" automatic link serve a useful purpose?

Comment: The feature was requested on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829/add-indication-that-canned-comments-are-from-review).

Answer (score 8):

It's useful for experienced users to be able to go to that review task sometimes, but I agree that this isn't the best user experience for the new guy whose first post, err, needs some work.  On smaller sites, in particular, if the user doesn't seem to be harmful but just misguided, we try to help him come in instead of sending him away.  Larger sites don't always have that luxury, due to sheer volume.

This is part of a larger issue: review tasks are visible to *anybody* if you have the URL.  You don't even have to be logged in.  So, while you need a certain amount of reputation to see these tasks *in the review queues*, you can see them just fine through other means.  And that's actually handy sometimes, particularly for moderators dealing with cross-site issues.

Maybe this compromise would work: If a user who doesn't have the review privilege follows a link to a review task, instead of seeing the name of the queue and the individual users and their votes, he sees a generic "Review" header and the *votes only* (not user names):

[image: review changes]

Comment: to me "review tasks are visible to _anybody_" is not an issue but very powerful and important feature. I believe that reviews should be as transparent as possible

Comment: @gnat they wouldn't change for users who have the review privilege, so they can still be audited.  I'm only talking about a change for low-rep users.  By the way, the names of the delete voters aren't exposed if the post is ultimately deleted via "recommend deletion" votes, either.

Comment: I understand that. I am for showing reviews to anyone, including low rep and readers who aren't logged in. We have enough troublesome reviews so having extra public scrutiny seems to be a good thing

Comment: @gnat Maybe there could be a different view (like the one in this answer) that's activated by a canned comment's link? Then there could be a little link somewhere on that page that shows the normal review info page.

Comment: @BenN I tend to think that making reviews visible to anyone is by design. Thing is, comments are not the only place where one can see how people review. Another place, also totally free to see for anyone is in [user profile -> activity -> reviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=activity&sort=reviews "example"). It does really look intended to be visible for anyone